# ¿Cómo escribir un método en un web service C# que devuelva un archivo .zip?

Tags: c#, webservice

Buenas tardes hermanos!

Me preguntaba ¿Cómo podría escribir ese método? lo que quiero hacer es que reciba el nombre de un archivo o parte del nombre, que si es más de un archivo los meta en un array y luego los comprima en .zip y lo retorne, trate de hacerlo mas o menos así. Aun no lo termino, soy nuevo y deseo mucho aprender, o si pueden proporcionarme información de donde buscar se los agradecería muchísimo.

Saludos!

[WebMethod]

```
public Object buscarFactura(string nombreFactura)
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\Axiliar_Sistemas\Desktop\facturas";
    string [] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

   //buscar en el array y después comprimir

    //
    return files;
}
```

Comment: No me queda claro si estás preguntando como devolver un archivo zip, como comprimir varios archivos en un zip, o si son ambas a la vez. Si son ambas, mi recomendación sería hacer 2 preguntas separadas y luego juntas tu las piezas para producir tu solución. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Es ambas, buscar varios archivos y comprimirlos en un zip, y retrornarlo como arreglo de bytes para capturarlo con php. thanks hermano y una disculpa, haré 2 preguntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si analizamos la documentacion

[HOW TO: Send and Receive Binary Documents by Using an ASP.NET Web Service and Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/es-ar/help/318425/how-to-send-and-receive-binary-documents-by-using-an-asp-net-web-servi)

veras que se devuelve un `byte[]` para retornar el archivo

```
[WebMethod]
public byte[] GetDocument(string DocumentName)
{
}
```

en el ejemplo usa el `FileStream` para obtener el byte[], pero hay una forma mas simple si usas el `File.ReadAllBytes()`

```
byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes("path archivo");
```

asi el codigo es mas simple

Comment: Gracias hermano!